# How to add Android.Dialog as an Android Fragment inside an Android Activity?

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Using MvvmCross, I would like to know how to use `Android.Dialog` inside Android Fragments.

On iOS, we can just add an instance of `DialogViewController` as a child of a parent view controller:

```
var Dialog = new DialogViewController (root);

viewController.AddChildViewController (Dialog);
viewController.View.AddSubview (Dialog.View);
```

Is it possible to write something related for Android? That is, adding an Android.Dialog Fragment inside an Activity on run-time?

```
... OnCreate (Bundle bundle) {
...

var Dialog = new DialogListFragment ();
Dialog.Root = root;

var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
transaction.Replace (Resource.Id.DialogFrame, Dialog);
transaction.Commit ();
```

I have just tried the above code, which compiles, but fails during run-time:
`[Android.Dialog] LoadLayout failed: You must call DroidResources.Initialise(Resource.Layout) before using Dialogs`

Finally, when adding the same root element to an instance of MvxDialogActivity, it is working properly.

DialogListFragment source code: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/fffe39c9e3a9eae24e55fdf58cf6f84d71a4654d/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/Dialog/DialogListFragment.cs

Did some of you guys implemented something related?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported 'out-of-the-box' in the current MvvmCross source - but it should be relatively straight-forward to merge the fragments and Activity-dialog code in order to create a working sample.

---

The exception you list is thrown from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossUI/CrossUI.Droid/DroidResources.cs#L99

It suggests that the Setup hasn't been called - in the standard samples (e.g. N+1 video samples) this is called via https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Droid/MvxAndroidDialogSetup.cs#L45

So this suggests you should check the setup in your code sample - are the resources being initialised?

Comment: Thank @Stuart. It is working now! I have just updated my SplashScreen class to inherit from `MvxSplashScreenActivity` instead of `Activity` as commented into the N=0 episode. The original DialogListFragment is also working as expected.